# column '_id' does not exist - SQLite Android INNER JOIN

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

So i keep getting this error message and im struggling to understand why as i know that the database has _id in every table.  This is error i am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

It is occurring when i am trying to execute an INNER JOIN statement that will link my two tables and get all Plastics, but linking the Items Name, Price etc via this method:

```
public Cursor allPlastics()
{   
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
       "SELECT Item.Name, Item.EAN, Item.Price, Plastics.Type, Plastics.Regs " +
       "FROM Item INNER JOIN Plastics On Item._id = Plastics.ItemId", null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Anyone know why im getting this _id missing error?? _id is valid on every single table in the DB

Comment: iirc the cursor itself needs an `_id` column in its rowset; add `Item._id` to your select list and if it works, thats the case. (as opposed to the message indicating there is no such column in the table)

Comment: It isnt crashing anymore but il try and debug to see if its doing the join correctly.  The statement should work i think. Thanks.